# Mixing Qt and Objective-C on Windows

Tags: c++, objective-c, windows, macos, qt

I usually develop application on OSX and iOS. I found that Objective-C is quite useful for many tasks and, in many cases, can speed up work.

I would like to port my applications also on Windows systems. I realized (if you have any other solutions please let me know!) that Qt could be a quite useful tool! Creating GUI with Qt is simple and fast. The problem is that Qt works with C++ and OSX works with Objective-C.

I read that Qt can handle Objective-C sources, in fact you can find the `OBJECTIVE_SOURCES` and `OBJECTIVE_HEADERS` makefile variables.

I searched how to configure Qt Creator to accept `.mm` files, but I was not able to get it to work.

Inside the `.pro` file I have something like following:

```
    ...
    OBJECTIVE_SOURCES += \
        test.mm
    INCLUDEPATH += "C:\GNUStep\...\Headers" 
    LIBS += -L"C:\GNUStep\...\Libraries" -lobjc -lgnustep-base
    QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -fconstant-string-class=NSConstantString -std=c99
    ...
```

My very simple project is a widget (`.h` and `.cpp`), the `main.cpp` and `test.h` with its `test.mm`. To mix C++ and Objective-C I thought about a "bridge" (just like I do in the Cocoa when mixing Objective-C and C++), so I create the `test.h` as a simple header (no Objective-C, only a bridge):

```
    // test.h
    void testFunction( void );
```

than:

```
    // test.mm
    #import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

    void testFunction( void ) {
       NSString* string;

       string = @"This is a test string";
       NSLog( @"%@", string ); 
    }
```

finally:

```
    // main.cpp
    ...
    #include "test.h"

    ...
    testFunction();
    ...
```

The linker gives me the classic "undefined reference to function testFunction". Something like it can not link the `.o` object files created from `.mm` files.

Can anyone of you tell me if something is wrong with this process or points me to a tutorial on how to configure Qt to accept Objective-C language?

There is another solution that I really like, it's pure Objective-C, i.e. using the GNUStep Gorm interface builder, but, unfortunately, GUIs built with Gorm are completely not accessible with accessibility tools like Jaws or NVDA, and I need to create some applications for visually impaired people!

Thank you very much

Answer (score 2):

The linker error "undefined reference to function testFunction", I suspect is due to a lack of something being defined in the testFunction.

You're right in that to mix Objective-c with Qt you simply create a header with C functions and an implementation file with a .m or .mm extension in which you can write objective-c code and reference the implementation in the .pro under OBJECTIVE_SOURCES

As you're using objective-c and classes such as [NSString](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html), you're also going to need to link to the relevant framework(s). In this case, it's Foundation.

So, in your config (.pro) file:-

```
LIBS += -framework Foundation
```

If you want to add another, such as Appkit, it would then be:-

```
LIBS += -framework Foundation 
LIBS += -framework AppKit
```

The only other addition to my .pro files when I mix the languages is this:-

```
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -F/Library/Frameworks
QMAKE_CFLAGS += -F/Library/Frameworks
QMAKE_LFLAGS += -F/Library/Frameworks
```

As you reference NSString in the test function implementation, you'll need to include its definition, so just add it to the includes, as you would normally do in an Objective-C program:-

```
#import <Foundation/NSString.h>
```

Comment: Thanks, now I will try this. Really I included the Foundation.h in test.mm, i forgot to mention.

Comment: Well... I do not have c:\GNUStep\...\Library\Frameworks in my installation folder, and "LIBS += -framework ..." gives the "unrecognized option -framework", maybe I miss something, or I simplified your suggestions... Could you please give me another hint?

Comment: C:\GNUStep... is a Windows path, not OSX!

Comment: I've corrected the example regarding -framework option.

Comment: @Marlin069 I this question is about mixing Qt and objc on Windows! So the objc compilers, as I know, is GNUStep...

Comment: Ah, sorry I missed that. Ok, so where are we up to then? You'll need to reference the frameworks that are provided by GNUStep. The "LIBS += framework Foundation" automatically knows where to find Foundation on OS X as it's integral to the OS, so I expect you need to substitute the correct path to the Foundation framework with something like LIBS += -framework <PATHTOLIBS>\Foundation

Comment: `LIBS += -framework AppKit` throws Linking Error, even without that application compiles